# when publishing rails application to heroku, it does not work anymore

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I added some like/dislike functionality to my app.  Everything has been working fine on heroku, and everything still works fine in production.  But when I pushed to heroku, it doesnt work anymore.  I tried running heroku run rake db:migrate several times, specifying the version of ruby in my gem file (1.9.3), and recreating the heroku app.  not sure why it works fine in development but wets the bed in production

here are my heroku logs:

```
2013-07-23T04:47:14.714935+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
2013-07-23T04:47:14.714935+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
2013-07-23T04:47:14.714935+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
2013-07-23T04:47:14.714935+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
2013-07-23T04:47:14.714935+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
2013-07-23T04:47:14.715229+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
2013-07-23T04:47:14.715229+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `require'
2013-07-23T04:47:14.715229+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2013-07-23T04:47:16.033612+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-07-23T04:47:16.053842+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-07-23T04:57:38.666709+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-07-23T04:58:59.531570+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 35635`
2013-07-23T04:59:39.923304+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to down
2013-07-23T04:59:45.880294+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.
as-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-07-23T04:59:45.880294+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.
as-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-07-23T04:59:52.132366+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2013-07-23T04:59:52.132366+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.13 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:35635
2013-07-23T04:59:52.132366+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2013-07-23T04:59:52.132366+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2013-07-23T04:59:52.132366+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2013-07-23T04:59:52.133728+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:55:in `method_missing': undefined method `before_image_post_process' for #<Class:0x00000003158238> (NoMethodError)
2013-07-23T04:59:52.133728+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/paperclip-3.5.0/lib/paperclip/validators.rb:58:in `create_validating_before_filter'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.133728+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/paperclip-3.5.0/lib/paperclip/validators/attachment_content_type_validator.rb:78:in `validates_attachment_content_type'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.133728+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/app/models/pin.rb:9:in `<class:Pin>'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.133911+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/app/models/pin.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.133728+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/paperclip-3.5.0/lib/paperclip/validators.rb:49:in `each'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.133728+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/paperclip-3.5.0/lib/paperclip/validators.rb:49:in `validate_before_processing'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.133728+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/paperclip-3.5.0/lib/paperclip/validators.rb:51:in `block in validate_before_processing'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.133728+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/paperclip-3.5.0/lib/paperclip/validators.rb:40:in `block in validates_attachment'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.133728+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/paperclip-3.5.0/lib/paperclip/validators.rb:32:in `each'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.133728+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/paperclip-3.5.0/lib/paperclip/validators.rb:32:in `validates_attachment'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.133911+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.133911+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.133911+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.133911+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.133911+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_or_load'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.133911+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:502:in `load_missing_constant'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.133911+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.133911+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `each'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.133911+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.134072+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `block in constantize'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.134072+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `each'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.134072+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `constantize'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.134072+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:260:in `safe_constantize'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.134072+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:66:in `safe_constantize'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.134072+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:152:in `_default_wrap_model'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.134072+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:169:in `_set_wrapper_defaults'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.134072+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:133:in `inherited'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.134072+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/abstract_controller/railties/routes_helpers.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in with'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.134072+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/railties/paths.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in with'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.134560+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/app/controllers/pins_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.134560+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.134560+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.134560+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.134560+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.134560+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_or_load'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.134560+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:313:in `depend_on'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.134560+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.134560+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.134560+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.134734+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `block in eager_load!'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.134734+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `each'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.134734+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.134734+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.134734+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.134734+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.134734+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.134734+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.134734+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.134734+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.135063+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.135063+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.135063+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.135063+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.135063+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.135063+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.135063+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.135063+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.135063+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.135219+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.135063+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.135219+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.135219+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.135219+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.135219+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.135219+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.135219+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.135219+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.135219+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.135219+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.135550+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.135550+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `require'
2013-07-23T04:59:52.135550+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2013-07-23T04:59:53.382360+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-07-23T05:21:56.106289+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=www.oinkbay.com fwd="66.249.75.216" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-07-23T05:43:51.030933+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/assets/Pigb-c122571e288ec48af85914695af78375.png host=www.oinkbay.com fwd="66.249.75.200" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-07-23T07:12:47.538191+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/assets/bigpig3-77ff62e72c2ea35d6ecd6e1f9f8931b7.png host=www.oinkbay.com fwd="66.249.75.43" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-07-23T08:17:27.816539+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/assets/woofberryteam-c20133a1beac5db9a2c2b391dc1a5895.png host=www.oinkbay.com fwd="66.249.75.167" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-07-23T10:34:36.299993+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/assets/Pig3b-8408e8eb48bc9f6a51572d729d297bf1.png host=www.oinkbay.com fwd="66.249.75.114" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-07-23T13:19:15.200220+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2013-07-23T13:19:20.080549+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command
```

Comment: *solved*
The problem is I didnt use a specific version of paperclip in my gem file and the newers version that was used on heroku no worky

Answer (score 1):

*solved*
The problem is I didnt use a specific version of paperclip in my gem file and the newers version that was used on heroku no worky

Answer (score 1):

The paperclip gem was updated in July 19 to 3.5, which appears to contain a routing error.

Best to specify the previous version in your gemfile (3.4.2)

```
gem 'paperclip', '3.4.2'
```